# Task.Run - Handling exceptions

Tags: vb.net, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am having a function as below (kept only relevant code for this example):

```
Public Async Function RefreshCompanyCodesAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
   For ctr=1 to 2000
      Await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(False)
      If ctr=5 Then Throw New ApplicationException("Why 5?") 
   Next
   return true
End Function
```

As you can see, I am generating an exception when ctr = 5 just to check how the exception will be handled in the UI.

I then call this function inside a button click `Async` event:

```
Dim task1 = Task.Run(Sub()
                          RefreshCompanyCodesAsync()
                     End Sub)
Dim cTask = task1.ContinueWith(Sub(antecedent)
                                           If task1.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion Then
                                               MsgBox("All done")
                                           ElseIf task1.Status = TaskStatus.Faulted Then
                                               MsgBox(task1.Exception.GetBaseException().Message)
                                           End If
                                       End Sub)
```

The task runs to completion instead of being faulted. I am guessing thats because a wrapper task runs to completion instead of the original task that threw an exception. However, am not sure how to get to the original task and handle the exception.

I have tried with `Await`.

```
    Try
        Await RefreshCompanyCodesAsync()
    Catch ax As AggregateException
        MsgBox(ax.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Exceptions get caught here, but the problem is I need to start multiple functionalities in parallel of which `RefreshCompanyCodesAsync` is only one of them. To do that, I believe launching those functionalities via Task.Run would be the best bet.

The actual functionality of the worker function in my case involves extensive DB and `HttpClient` activity and during this time, the UI responsiveness is driving me towards going in for `Task.Run` or `Factory.StartNew`

Also, have tried launching the task and Waiting for it so as to ensure evaluation of the result. However, my UI gets blocked when I do `Task.Wait`.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, what you want is

```
Dim task1 = RefreshCompanyCodesAsync()
```

That way there is no wrapper task. `RefreshCompanyCodesAsync` already is non-blocking which is important so that you don't freeze the UI.

You should avoid `ContinueWith`. Prefer await because it marshals you back to the UI thread.

I'll need to write this in C#:

```
var task1 = RefreshCompanyCodesAsync();
await Task.WhenAny(task1); //Wait without throwing.
MessageBox.Show(task1.Status.ToString());
```

Comment: Thx. But is there any difference between this and `Await RefreshCompanyCodesAsync()` as long as there is only one task?

Comment: Await would throw and abort the control flow. It would force you to catch. Exception handling for control flow is to be avoided. This is immaterial to the answer, though.